# Can we "click" on edit boxes using Microsoft UIAutomation libraries

Tags: ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation, uia

In my application, we have a webbrowserpageviewer control. when a webpage is opened, user needs to click on some of the editboxes present on the webpage. We are trying to simulate this behvior using UI Automation libraries. Am a bit new to this but I see that we can simulate button clicks using InvokePattern so is there any similar method to simulate editbox clicks?

Comment: What do you mean by "editbox"? Do you mean an `<input type=text>` tag?

Comment: Sorry for the late replay... Yes, I meant <input type=text>

Comment: You want to enter the edit (focus) and push text to it? also, what's "webbrowserpageviewer"?

Comment: Are you coding this or recording? If coding, which language? see this link for the how-to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465184(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You have two ways as far as i know to edit the text boxes:

1.You can add a text in text box using a pattern provided by UIA.
This pattern is called ValuePattern.

In C# you can do this in this way:

```
ValuePattern vp = element_object.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
vp.SetValue(value_to_set);
```

2.You can get the bounding rectangle of text box using the AutomationElement properties after that you can click within it.

Getting bounding rectangle in c#:

```
automationelement_object.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty)
```